# How to make an object parcelable through a generic class

Tags: java, android, parcelable, android-handler

I have to send and receive objects between a smartphone and a remote desktop (running Java) via Bluetooth. The smartphone and desktop both share a series of classes that constitutes the application data model.

I need to implement the Parcelable interface on the smartphone app so that when receiving an object from the desktop app, I can send it back to the main activity via a Handler. Unfortunately, this wouldn't work because it would make the classes unusable on the desktop app.

So my question is : Can I send the objects without the Parcelable interface implemented to the desktop app and then make them Parcelable through a generic class when receiving them.

Something like that :

```
Object orgObject = new Object();

//Make an object Parcelable
ObjectParcelable objPble = GenericClass.makeParcelable(orgObject);

//Remove the Parcelable implementation
orgObject = GenericClass.undoParcelable(objPble);
```

Comment: How about using seriallization. You can send and recieve as streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred solution for this problem is serializing the object to JSON (for example, using the Gson library) and sending it as a string. Then on the other side you can deserialize the JSON to an object using your preferred library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the object that you would like to send to some intermediate format like json or xml for instance. Then you can send this serialized message from the android side and deserialize it on the java side, and vice versa. You can use for that a library that works the same way on android and java, for instance https://github.com/google/gson. In this way you can use same java class files, for your model in both applications.